# Spring boot inside docker container throws java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

Tags: java, docker, spring-boot, kitematic

The **client** application sends `json` data to server on localhost:8080 that is packaged and run as docker image. Servers work fine when manually sending json using Postman chrome app. The problem is with dockerized **client** that throws `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)` when trying to write `json` to `HttpURLConnection` using `OutputStreamWriter`. How to make it work?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ARG JAR_FILE=target/client-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
EXPOSE 8088
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

Comment: Is the client running in a different container from the server?

Comment: You need to link your containers

Comment: @teppic, yes they run in different containers

Comment: can you post the `docker run` command here, i believe you're missing port mapping ?

Comment: from postman, are you able to do http://localhost:8080 and get to your service ?

Comment: @Jayesh, it is possible to access app from postman on localhost:8080 . I use Kitematic to run containers, not sure about `docker run`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both clients should run on the same network. 
So create a network bridge `MY_BRIDGE`:

```
docker network create MY_BRIDGE
```

Attach both container to the bridge, when running them. Give the server container a name `MY_SERVER`:

```
docker run --network MY_BRIDGE --name MY_SERVER MY_SERVER_IMAGE

docker run --network MY_BRIDGE MY_CLIENT_IMAGE
```

Your application code has to be changed from `localhost:8080` to `MY_SERVER:8080` prior to running the client container.

See [Docker Bridge Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/)

Answer (score 0):

In docker each container has it's own virtualised network stack - *localhost* is the address of the container's loopback interface, not the address of the host's loopback interface.

You'll have to configure your client to connect to the server using its hostname. Simply the container name of the server if you're using `docker-compose`, or the hostname of the docker host machine if you're running the containers up manually.

Reference: [Networking with standalone containers](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/).

Comment: I don't understand what changes need to be made to the client app. Changing URL from `http://localhost:8080` to `http://docker_server-app_1:8080` produced error `java.net.UnknownHostException: docker_server-app_1`

Comment: I added a doc link to the answer.